# energy changes in an accelarated electron

Tags: atomic-physics

why doesn't the electron fall into the nucleus if it is emitting radiation (accelerating charge emit radiation) . i have come to know they emit E=h*frequency waves, or does it get any energy?

Comment: Why do you think it's accelerating?

Comment: This is exactly the question that Bohr asked, which he solved by creating the Bohr model of Hydrogen. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model

Comment: @hft change in direction

Comment: Change in direction of what?

Answer (score 0):

> why doesn't the electron fall into the nucleus if it is emitting
>   radiation (accelerating charge emit radiation) . i have come to know
>   they emit E=h*frequency waves, or does it get any energy?

If the electron orbiting the nucleus is in a *stationary state*, i.e., a state of fixed energy as defined by a solution to the stronger equation
$$
\hat H \Psi = E \Psi
$$
then its energy does not change with time, nor does the expectation value any other variable such as position, velocity, etc. This is because
$$
\frac{d\hat O}{dt}=i[\hat H,\hat O]
$$
and so, in a stationary state $|\Psi\rangle$
$$
\frac{<O>}{dt}=i<[\hat H,\hat O]>=<O>(E-E)=0
$$
In particular
$$
\frac{d\langle \hat v\rangle}{dt}=0
$$